# Prepend printed string with its final newlines to a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, newline, command-substitution

I have the following function defined in bash:

```
function print_revision {
    printf "Revision %s (%s)\n%s\n\n" "$1" "$(date --utc +%d.%m.%Y,\ %H:%M\ UTC)" \
    "----------------------------------------"
}
```

I also have a variable, `$CHANGES` with some text in it. What I would need to do is prepend the string printed in `print_revision` to the `$CHANGES` variable.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
CHANGES="$(print_revision $CURRENT_SHORT_REVISION)"$CHANGES
```

It prepends everything from `print_revision` but it goes through the last two newline characters, concatenating the contents of `$CHANGES` right after the `-----` part.

How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: Note that the `function` keyword makes your scripts gratuitously incompatible with POSIX sh, and provides no advantages over the POSIX syntax of `funcname() { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to just print the current value of `$CHANGES` inside the command substitution:

```
CHANGES="$(print_revision $CURRENT_SHORT_REVISION; echo "$CHANGES")"
```

Comment: I've gone with this variant since it is the simplest to implement in the given situation. Though I will consider the other variants from now on.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use command substitution here.

```
printf -v var_name format_string arg1 arg2 ...
```

...stores the output of the printf directly into `var_name`, without any subshell involved (more efficient!), and no command substitution (no stripping of trailing newlines!)

Thus:

```
print_revision_to() {
    printf -v "$1" \
      "Revision %s (%s)\n%s\n\n" \
      "$2" \
      "$(date --utc +%d.%m.%Y,\ %H:%M\ UTC)" \
      "----------------------------------------"
}

# ...thus, to put a header for revision 13 into "$changes", you'd run...
print_revision_to changes 13
```

...or, if you want to do this all at once...

```
prepend_revision_header_to() {
    printf -v "$1" \
      "Revision %s (%s)\n%s\n\n%s" \
      "$2" \
      "$(date --utc +%d.%m.%Y,\ %H:%M\ UTC)" \
      "----------------------------------------"
      "${!1}"
}

# ...thus, to modify the existing value of "$changes" by putting a header
# at the beginning, you'd run...
prepend_revision_header_to changes 13
```

Comment: And then, instead of calling the function, I will use `$changes`?

Comment: @AndreiHorak, you call the function, and then use `"$changes"`, yes. Alternately, you can pass the name of the variable to store its output into as an argument, and `printf -v "$2"` to store the formatted string into that variable.

Comment: Alright, but I also need to prepend this to an already defined variable. Isn't it extra work to assign a print to a variable inside a function, then prepend that variable to an existing one?

Comment: @AndreiHorak, it's much less work than a subshell. Command substitutions are (performance wise) very expensive. Don't take my word for it -- run a benchmark doing each of the two approaches 1000 times, and compare the numbers; it's an orders-of-magnitude difference.

Comment: @AndreiHorak ...I also added a simple modification which prepends as a single pass.

Comment: @AndreiHorak ...mind you, you're already having a fairly substantial amount of constant-factor performance overhead by way of the call to `date`, which is necessarily an external process (thus requiring the whole fork/exec/wait rigamarole). If you only needed to support very modern versions of bash, you could use `%(%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M UTC)T` with a paired argument of `-1` to generate the date in-process with no fork.

Answer (score 2):

Command substitution strips off newlines at the end of the string. The typical use case is that the output ends with a newline and is either going to be printed with another newline or concatenated with another string to make up a single line (e.g. `echo $(echo part1)$(echo part2)`).

If you can't or don't want to change the `print_revision` function, print a non-newline character after it, then strip it off.

```
new_revision=$(print_revision $CURRENT_SHORT_REVISION; echo a); new_revision=${new_revision%a}
CHANGES=$new_revision$CHANGES
```

Alternatively, put as many newlines as you want in the concatenation.

```
CHANGES="$(print_revision $CURRENT_SHORT_REVISION)

$CHANGES"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ man bash
...
Command Substitution
...
Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the com‐
mand substitution with the standard output of  the  command,  with  any
trailing newlines deleted.
```

Hence the use of $(...) is removing the trailing newlines.

If you want to keep a separate print_revision function then one approach would be to avoid trailing newlines in its output by appending a sentinel in print_revision, then stripping that off when you use it:

```
function print_revision {
    printf "Revision %s (%s)\n%s\n\n___" ...
}

REVISION="$(print_revision $CURRENT_SHORT_REVISION)"
CHANGES="${REVISION%___}$CHANGES"
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to pass the existing value (if any) into the function:

```
prepend_revision() {
  printf "Revision %s (%s)\n%s\n\n%s" \
         "$1" "$(date --utc +%d.%m.%Y,\ %H:%M\ UTC)" \
         "----------------------------------------" "$2"
}

CHANGES=$(prepend_revision "$CURRENT_SHORT_REVISION" "$CHANGES")
```

Note that if you call `prepend_revision` with only one argument, the output is exactly the same as the existing `print_revision` function, so it can be used either to create or prepend.

Comment: I know, but that function will be used in other places as well, where I do not have the `$CHANGES` variable to append.

Comment: @AndreiHorak: If you leave out the second argument, the result is the same as your original function. So you can use it in either context.